# Excel services refresh using Claims based NTLM?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel, excel-services, secure-store, sql-analysis-services

I am able to upload reports in a sharepoint library that have embedded data connections to a cube(SQL2008\AnalysisInstance). We are not using power pivot. We are running Sql 2008 standard version.

However I cannot seem to refresh it as windows credentials are not being delegated. 
So I tried creating a secure store service target app "ExcelTargetApp" and use that in Excel. I have used 'group' under the target application type.

The error before and the error after.
[image]

[image]

What are my options to get around this?

1. Do I create an Unattended service account in SSS?
2. Can I modify the current solution in any way to make it work?
3. Although I am aware that changing to Kerberos might fix the double hop problem I do not want to unless Im left with no other choice and additionally we do not really have a need for it.

Or am I just missing something easy and obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a secure store target app for excel and used the SSS ID in my excel reports. 
It refreshes without any errors now.

Answer (score 0):

In general: when using SAML-based authentication, the identity of the user cannot be delegated to backend systems, like SQL Server.

See here: http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2014/08/08/microsoft-bi-on-premise-forget-saml-authentication/